# Rspec expectation for subclass method

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec

I want to test this code:

```
smtp = Net::SMTP.start(config[:server])
```

with this spec:

```
expect(Net::SMTP).to receive(:start).with('testserver')
```

but take this error:

```
Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
SystemStackError:
  stack level too deep
```

What am I missing? Should I use something like fakeweb for stubbing this activity or expect functional is enough for this stage?

Comment: Should it be `expect(smtp).to receive(:start).with('testserver')`

Comment: try `expect(Net::SMTP).to receive(:start).with('testserver').and_return {|t| super(t)}`

Comment: @Bala, I don't think so. It returns error: `undefined local variable or method 'smtp' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Mailer:0x000000011165b0 @__memoized=nil>`.

Comment: @BroiSatse, `wrong number of arguments (0 for 1+)`. I have no idea what arguments it is about.

Comment: @Michael - Any backtrace?

Comment: @BroiSatse, only `./spec/mailer_spec.rb:6:in 'block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'`, which is actually string you recommended.

Comment: Perhaps it will help to share the entire test? I was able to create a passing spec with your two lines and defining a config.

Comment: @JustinKo, thanks a lot! Error reason was in other spec lines. I fixed it.